# jQuery UI sortable and draggable

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draggable

Im working on an application where I need to be able to drag boxes in an invisible 80x80 grid, which I accomplished using jQuery UI draggable. What I need to accomplish though is when I drag a box onto another one, they switch places. So say I drag box #1 over box #2, box #2 goes to the previous "cell" on the grid that box #1 was before it was dragged over box #2. so basically swap places. If anyone knows how to accomplish this it would be appreciated.

Comment: It might help to know more about the nature of your grid and what it looks like. Are all of the boxes adjacent, like grid paper? Or are they more free-form like a modeling tool?